# Add own custom values on top of the ones returned by the template query

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I'm using [query options](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/#query-options) to define the values in my drop down which works quite well.

Besides the variables fetched by the query I'd like to add my own ones. Is that possible?

e.g. my dropdown would look like below

- custom value 1
- custom value 2
- query value 1
- query value 2
- query value 3

etc.